# Not all Specflow Hooks are executed when running tests on vstest.console with NUnit3TestAdapter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, specflow, azure-pipelines

We use the visualstudio.com Release Manager to tell a local Build Agent to build and execute a set of SpecFlow tests on the Build Agent-machine, pulling from a GIT-branch.

We're using the Test Assemblies-task with a Custom Test Adapter (NUnit3TestAdapter 3.7.0) and point it toward the assembly containing the SpecFlow tests. Other assemblies inside the same bin folder contain SpecFlow-Hooks that execute setup and teardown-hooks.

The problem we're facing is that not all of these Hooks seem to called. The first and last messages in the .trx logs are all from `[BeforeScenario]` and `[AfterScenario]` hooks. There are -however- `[BeforeTestRun]`, `[AfterTestRun]` and `[BeforeFeature]` hooks in the same assemblies.

I've pasted the (abridged) logs from VSTS below:

> Executing vstest.console.exe
>   "*DLL CONTAINING TESTS*"
>   /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=MP2"
>   /Settings:"C:\agent_work\r17\a\TestResults\1_2017-05-31_09-31-50-AM.runsettings"
>   /logger:trx
>   /TestAdapterPath:"C:\agent_work\r17\a\drop\b\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.7.0\tools"
>
> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
>   Tool Version 14.0.25420.1 2017-05-31T07:31:51.1862622Z Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting
>   test execution, please wait...
>
> Information: NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test execution started
>
> Information: Running all tests in
>   C:\agent_work\r17\a\drop\b\*DLL CONTAINING TESTS*
>
> Information: NUnit3TestExecutor converted 472 of 472 NUnit test cases

Then the logging from the tests itself, starting with messages from `BeforeScenario`.

I'm at a loss as to why the other hooks are never called. Does NUnit3TestAdapter even keep track of a TestRun context? Is it because the Before/AfterTestRun and Before/AfterFeature-hooks are bound to static methods? Or is it possible they ARE executed, but the messages are never passed through to the .trx logs?

Comment: Does `[BeforeScenario]` and `[AfterScenario]` hooks in a .cs file, and other hooks in another .cs file? I can find the output in `.trx` file. Or can you share your project in one drive?

Comment: Only to be sure, do you have on the classes with the hooks the [Binding] attribute? This is also needed for hooks and not only for bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `[BeforeTestRun]`
 was being called perfectly fine, but just didn't show up in the logs. The problem was with `[AfterTestRun]`, which turns out to be an [old bug](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/26) in SpecFlow that was never really fixed (?)

Comment: Still not fixed and they went .NET Core, but haven't fixed the hook.